# Composer can't install own packagist package, minimum-stability error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have own package at github I created tag with name: "1.0.0".
composer.json in this tag don not have "minimum-stability" property (I tried with "minimum-stability": "dev" and "minimum-stability": "stable") but same error appears.

Error that I get is:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package am2studio/laravel-table-sorter 1.* could not be found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I am trying to install package with

```
"comp-x/package-x": "1.*"
```

in composer and this error appears, with:

```
"comp-x/package-x": "dev-master"
```

everything is fine, and composer installs my package. Do you know what is problem here ?

Comment: Have you push the package to packagist ?

Comment: yes problem was that there has been only master-dev on pacakagist.